# R structuring data to allow side-by-side comparisons

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, how do you compare, in a single graph, Scheduled Use and Actual Use?

I can display a bar graph of Scheduled Use, or a bar graph of Actual Use, but I can't figure out how to show a bar graph that shows Scheduled next to Actual

I have the following table of data.

| Room | ToD | Scheduled Use | Actual Use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Morning | 37.5 | 22.3 |
| A | Afternoon | 27 | 15.3 |
| A | Evening | 6.3 | 2 |
| B | Morning | 18 | 24 |
| B | Afternoon | 27 | 27 |
| B | Evening | 6.5 | 12.3 |
| C | Morning | 15.8 | 7.5 |
| C | Afternoon | 20 | 10.3 |
| C | Evening | 12.8 | 18 |
| D | Morning | 10 | 7.5 |
| D | Afternoon | 10 | 7.5 |
| D | Evening | 18 | 12.3 |

This is how I plot the Scheduled Use, with an example of the plot.

```
# Read the csv data
x <- read.csv("C:/Users/David/Desktop/R-ggplot.csv")
View(x)

# Re-level to show on facet as: Morning, Afternoon, Evening
# insteat of: Afternoon, Evening, Morning
x$ToD <- factor(x$ToD, levels = c("Morning",
                                  "Afternoon",
                                  "Evening"))

# Plot the graph
y <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = `Room`,
                          y = `Scheduled.Use`,
                          fill = `ToD`)) +
    geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
    facet_wrap(~`ToD`, nrow = 3) +
    ggtitle("Room Scheduled Use v. Actual Use") +
    ylab("Scheduled v. Acutual")
plot(y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot expects it to be in "long" format, so you need to pivot_longer first. When you pivot to longer, the name of the columns being pivoted becomes a new column called "name", and the value of the column becomes a column called "value" (look at the output for just the first part of the pipe chain right after pivot_longer to see what I mean). If you want the columns in a different order, you need to convert "name" to factor and specify the levels in the order you want.

```r
x <- read.delim(text = '
Room    ToD Scheduled.Use   Actual.Use
A   Morning 37.5    22.3
A   Afternoon   27  15.3
A   Evening 6.3 2
B   Morning 18  24
B   Afternoon   27  27
B   Evening 6.5 12.3
C   Morning 15.8    7.5
C   Afternoon   20  10.3
C   Evening 12.8    18
D   Morning 10  7.5
D   Afternoon   10  7.5
D   Evening 18  12.3
')

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

sched_act_plot <- 
  x %>% 
    mutate(across(ToD, factor, levels = c("Morning",
                                          "Afternoon",
                                          "Evening"))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(Scheduled.Use,   Actual.Use)) %>% 
    mutate(across(name, factor, levels = c('Scheduled.Use', 
                                            'Actual.Use'))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Room, y = value, fill = name)) +
      geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
      facet_wrap(~ToD, nrow = 3) +
      ggtitle("Room Scheduled Use v. Actual Use") +
      ylab("Scheduled v. Acutual")

plot(sched_act_plot)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Might be helpful to add `library(tidyr)` or `library(tidyverse)` at the top to get the pipe (`%>%`) and `pivot_longer`, as it's unclear OP has loaded any packages beyond ggplot2.

Comment: I see your plot, but this is not working for me. I added in `tidyr` and `tidyverse` as per @Spring, and it didn't help. When I `plot(x)` I get a 4x4 grid of graphs with data as points. Is this the entire code, am I missing something in mine? I substituted your code for my `y <- ggplot...`  section.

Comment: Edited to make sure the process is completely reproducible from a new R session without running anything else (used reprex package)

Comment: I'm still not getting this to work - same results when I `plot(x)`. Do I need to add the `plot(x)` line? Asking because when running the code w/o it I don't get any plots.

Comment: You don’t need plot(x). Not sure why it wouldn’t work, running the code exactly as is should produce the plot (I copied directly from representing which is designed to verify there’s no other code or variables impacting the output). Have you tried opening a new session of R and running only this exact code?

Comment: Okay, this is weird. If I "Source" the code (RStudio) then I don't get a plot. However, I get the plot if I "Run" the `x %>%` code section (`x` is still in the Environment memory). Any ideas on this one? Also, couple of questions:  1) why `y = value` and `fill = name`? 2)  How to reverse plot order from Actual/Scheduled to Scheduled/Actual?

Comment: I put `plot(x %>% ...)` and it now works when Sourcing the code in RStudio. I'd still like to hear about the questions in my previous post.

Comment: Edited the answer to address these questions

Comment: This worked fantastically. Thank you for your time and patience.